# Kendo Window fixed position

Tags: javascript, css, kendo-ui

I have a kendo ui window like on [kendo example page](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/window/api). On Kendo example   page the window is a child of a #main div. That div has a calculated height. Therefor the window is fixed.
If I use it on my html app the window is not position fixed. It scrolls. 
I would like to have the behavior such as the kendo example. Window should fixed and background should be scrollable.

I set the position onDocumentReady like this:

```
.k-widget .k-window{
position:fixed; 
}
```

But I guess that isn't a good idea. How can I set the position in a better way?

Comment: I can't get your idea. Can you explain better or give an example? Kendo windows is pretty straightforward so It must be easy to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

As part of your window configuration, set the pinned and position options. For example:

```
pinned: true,
position: { top: 100 }
```

Any content beneath the window will then scroll, assuming it has focus, with the window staying in place.
Telerik docs: http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/window#configuration-pinned